# When can I expect the derivative of an inequality to always hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f,g$ be real-valued functions. Suppose I have an inequality $$f(x)>g(x)$$ for $x\in D$, where $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is some domain. After some "tinkering" I see that we can not always expect the result of taking the derivative to hold true. For example, with $$x^2+1>x,$$ which is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we obtain by taking the derivative, $$2x>1,$$ which is true only for $x>1/2$.

My question is: are there any non-trivial conditions on $f,g$ over the domain $D$ from which it follows from $f(x)>g(x)$ that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ over $D$ ?

Comment: Not really. The relation $f(x)>g(x)$ says nothing when it comes to comparing the 'measure in which $f$ and $g$ are increasing/decreasing'.

Comment: @ drhab Thanks. I found this, the answer to which implies the very same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64682/can-you-reduce-an-inequality-by-taking-a-derivative. Boo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments and in [Can you reduce an inequality by taking a derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64682/can-you-reduce-an-inequality-by-taking-a-derivative), the inequality $f(x) > g(x)$ does almost never entail $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ for all $x$.

But there is one instance in which one can derive some inequality for the derivative, namely if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in (x_0, x_0 + \varepsilon)$ **and** $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$, then the definition of the derivative yields (as long as $f,g$ are differentiable in $x_0$)

$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0 +h) - g(x_0)}{h} \leq \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{g(x_0 + h) - g(x_0)}{h} = g'(x_0).
$$

Also, one can of course use $f' \geq g'$ together with $f(x_0) \leq g(x_0)$ to derive $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \geq x_0$, but this is the **reverse** of what you are asking.